# WSPBuilder 80/resources folder not deploying files. Why?

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, wspbuilder, smartpart

I've created two folders under `80` folder, `resources` and `bin`. resources contains a folder `usercontrols` which has `ascx` file and bin has `dlls`. The purpose of having usercontrols folder under `80\resources` is I'm using smartpart and it need it to collect the usercontrols.

When I deploy using WSPBuilder deploy option nothing went into web application directory. No `usercontrols` and `bin` folder created.

I've googled and trying to find why is this happening as it is mentioned in the [documentation](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/45261#166101) of WSPBuilder the usage of `80\resources` folder that it can have any files.

Later, I found this:

> The WSPBuilder should not pick up
>   resources in folder 80/UserControl and
>   my test confirms this, however
>   12/UserControl will but this is
>   useless. The Class Resource files
>   follows the DLL, so files in
>   80/wpresources will be picked up and
>   deployed to "C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\wpresources" if the DLL is
>   deployed to the Global Assembly Cache.
>
> by keutmann ( the creator of WSPBuilder)

There is a contradiction between the documentation and the above statement. I'm completely confused and what does it mean to have a `80\resources` folder?

Why I needed `80\resources` folder is because I'm using **Return of SmartPart** and it required `usercontrols` folder in web application root to collect the User Controls.

Someone, suggest me to download the source of **SmartPart** and change it. Maintain your own version. This looks to me last choice to do. The source of **SmartPart** is avaliable on **codeplex** but there is no source code avaliable for **Return of SmartPart**. Left me no choice!

Help!

Thanks.

Comment: @Ramiz: You'll have to check the download but looking at the dates I think the source for Return of SmartPart is there under Recent Checkins: http://smartpart.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 1):

More information on resources (in this case within web parts but still relevant) can be found [here](http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spother/article.php/52301_3837501_1/Managing-Resources-in-a-Custom-Web-Part.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Charles! Seems a great info. Definitely read it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this site](http://www.allaboutmoss.com/index.php/2010/03/05/how-to-create-wsp-package-for-user-controls/) for deploying resources and usercontrols in moss.